# Task 'GenerateAppxPackageRecipe' failed. The specified module could not be found

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to run a UWP project in Visual Studio 2017 and keep encountering this error.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/mQbzx0J]

This error occurs with a new Blank UWP project as well.

I have tried using the same vsconfig as my colleague and even a full uninstall and reinstall of Visual Studio 2017 with no success. I am wondering if I might be missing a windows DLL as it is a Win32 error.

Comment: Please copy the error into your post as text.

Comment: use process monitor and look for NOT_FOUND events.